# Как отделить продолжение после пояснительной части?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, бсп, перечисление

*Когда человек думает, в реальном мире ничего не происходит: дела не делаются, проблемы не решаются, [—] но энергия расходуется.*

"Но энергия расходуется" относится к части предложения перед двоеточием, а не к двум поясняющим предложениям перед ним. Как это показать при помощи пунктуации? Подойдёт ли тире?

**Дополнение**

Предложение выше — часть поста в социальной сети о том, как сохранять свою энергию, чтобы в жизни больше успевать, реализовывать свои карьерные планы и т.   д.

Вот контекст с предложением, исправленным исходя из ответов участников сообщества.

> 4. Меньше думай
>
> Когда ты думаешь, в реальном мире от этого ничего не меняется: дела не делаются, проблемы не решаются, [—] но энергия при этом расходуется. Живи в настоящем моменте. Если есть проблема, но в данную секунду ты находишься там, откуда не можешь её решить, забудь о ней.

Вопрос о тире остаётся открытым.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, "к одному знаменателю": _но энергия расходуется_ или _но энергия **при этом** расходуется._

Comment: Исправил опечатку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение логически неверное: eсли в реальном мире ничего не происходит, то в каком мире происходит расход энергии? Его можно было бы подкорректировать, например, так:

**Когда человек думает, вокруг ничего не меняется: дела не делаются, проблемы не решаются, — но энергия расходуется.**

Думаю, в данном случае подойдет следующее правило:

> § 35. Тире ставится после перечисления однородных членов, если перечислением предложение не заканчивается: Повсюду: в клубе, на улицах, на скамейках у ворот, в домах — происходили шумные разговоры (Гарш.). ([ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=96))

Думаю, запятая перед *но* тоже ставится, по своей отдельной причине.

Comment: То есть вы приравняли это к однородным членам после обобщающего слова?

Comment: Не приравнял, а увидел здесь именно однородные члены после обобщающего слова.

Comment: А как именуются члены предложения, которые являются здесь однородными?

Comment: Я затрудняюсь с формальной частью. Это похоже на однородные придаточные, но это не СПП, а БСП. Возможно, слово "приравнять" здесь и в самом деле уместно.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве варианта, если автор именно это хотел сказать:

**Когда человек думает, то в реальном мире ничего не происходит: дела не делаются, проблемы не решаются, но его мыслительная энергия при этом расходуется.**

Comment: Этот упущенный момент (чья энергия?) мне тоже бросился в глаза, но и с его мыслями неплохо бы связать "остановившийся мир" (в реальном мире _от этого ничего не меняется_"), ведь в мире и без его участия что-то продолжает происходить, да ещё повсеместно.

Comment: По одному предложению, к тому же не вполне корректному, трудно судить, что хотел сказать автор, о расходе какой энергии идет речь.

Comment: Возможно, это и о расходе энергии в мире, но утверждение, что во время его размышлений в реальном мире ничего не происходит, вызывает более серьёзное недоверие к последующему описанию.

Comment: Я тоже сначала подумала о мировой энергии, но потом решила. что это энергия мысли. Вот пример из жизни. Лежит какая-то вещь не на месте, прохожу мимо и думаю: надо убрать.  Прохожу второй раз, третий, десятый,  Это сколько же мыслительной и эмоциональной энергии зря затратишь, пока наконец уберешь. И вывод: надо не думать над проблемами, а решать их сразу.

Comment: Jasmin, вы абсолютно верно поняли смысл фразы. Соглашусь с @Alex_ander: фраза некорректна — в реальном мире что-то всё равно происходит, даже если человек бездействует. Однако, если смотреть чисто формально, тире после запятой и перед "но" не нужна?

Comment: @Alex_ander Из контекста, в котором находится данное предложения, ясно, чья энергия имеется в виду. Я дополнил вопрос: указал контекст и при этом поставил в него исправленное предложение.