# Продолжение после конструкции с двоеточием

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, двоеточие, бсп

Уже задавал подобный вопрос ([Как отделить продолжение после пояснительной части?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443903/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)). Хотелось бы разобраться с другими примерами. Вызывают пунктуационные трудности ситуации, когда есть БСП с двоеточием, или пояснительная конструкция с двоеточием, или однородные члены после обобщающего слова, но затем идёт продолжение главной части предложения.

1. *При этом ни в коем случае не пишите свои цели по памяти: эффекта не будет[, —] пишите каждый раз будто впервые.*

Запятая между частями сложного предложения; тире, т.к. есть противопоставление.

2. *Если на этапе внедрения вы поняли: что‑то не идёт[, —] вернитесь к предыдущему этапу.*

Сразу скажу: перед "вернитесь" увеличенной паузы не предполагается. Поэтому интонационного тире здесь нет. Думаю насчёт тире как о дополнительном, более выразительном знаке после запятой, чтобы указать, что дальше пойдёт главное предложение.

3. *Иногда выполнять работу удобнее рывками, особенно когда она интеллектуальная и через час мозги уже закипают. Есть только одно исключение: вы вошли в кураж[, —] тогда прерываться не стоит.*

Запятая между частями сложного предложения; тире, чтобы показать, что дальнейшая часть предложения уже не является пояснением, а продолжает главную часть.

4. *При этом установите себе вознаграждение: тортик, сериал, просмотр интересных видео на YouTube[, —] выбирайте по вкусу.*

Запятая между частями сложного предложения; тире выражает интонацию присоединения, а также является более выразительным знаком после запятых между однородными членами.

**Вопрос**

Запятая, тире или запятая и тире?

Comment: Вопрос в чем?!!

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко _2. Если **на** этапе внедрения вы поняли..._ Так, наверное?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да. Спасибо)

Comment: @behemothus Запятая, тире или запятая и тире.

Answer (score 1):

Все предложения состоят **из трех** грамматических частей, но при этом они делятся на **два смысловых блока**, отношения между которыми надо обозначить. И во всех предложениях нужно поставить **единый знак "запятая и тире".**

Пояснение

Тире в данном случае обозначает **или присоединение,  или  противопоставление** (если пропущен союз А или местоименная часть союза ЕСЛИ...ТО).  Тире будет соответствовать паузе в устной речи (хотите вы этого или нет).  Запятой в этом случае недостаточно.

**Но одно тире с этой задачей не может справиться,** так как неясно, к чему оно относится: к двум первым частям или только ко второй.

Использование **единого знака для обозначения смысловых блоков** есть у Розенталя, в ПАС единый знак также упоминается. При этом нет смысла ориентироваться на какие-то формальные признаки употребления единого знака — он выбирается в том случае, если это **единственный способ определиться с функцией тире** при делении трехчастной конструкции на две части.

1. При этом ни в коем случае не пишите свои цели по памяти: эффекта не будет, — пишите каждый раз будто впервые.
2. Если этапе внедрения вы поняли: что‑то не идёт, —  вернитесь к предыдущему этапу.
3. Есть только одно исключение: вы вошли в кураж, — тогда прерываться не стоит.
4. При этом установите себе вознаграждение: тортик, сериал, просмотр интересных видео на YouTube, — выбирайте по вкусу.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Comment: Регулярно вижу на сайте, что некоторые участники аргументируют постановку тире в предложениях с союзом "если" пропуском "то" в составном союзе "если… то". Мне почему‑то это кажется притягиванием за уши — союз "если" чаще всего используется как раз без соотносительной части "то": *Если ты уйдёшь, я заплачу*.

Comment: Здесь надо поставить такой вопрос: для чего нужна местоименная часть союза ЕСЛИ...ТО?  Если не углубляться в источники, то  можно предположить, что местоимение ТО упрощает понимание предложения: с точки зрения грамматики оно становится взаимообусловленным. При отсутствии местоимения это не столь очевидно, поэтому пропускают ТО в нераспространенных предложениях. Также можно обратить внимание, что при отсутствии ТО нам приходится делать  ударение на первой части, а это увеличивает паузу между предложениями (в этом случае СПП по интонации напоминает БСП со значением условия).

Comment: Если же предложение распространенное, то наличие местоимения необходимо в большей степени. Особенно это относится к сложным конструкциям, когда подчинительный  союз ЕСЛИ находится на значительном расстоянии от главного предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Меня смутило, что вы называете "то" местоимением. Его можно назвать формой среднего рода указательного местоимения "тот" и соотносительным словом в предложениях типа: *Особенно страшно было то, что над огнем в дыму летали голуби* (Чехов). В нашем случае же местоимением его назвать сложно. Его обычно определяют как **вторая часть двойного союза "если… то"**.

Comment: По-моему, местоименная часть союза - это обычный термин. Так говорится про сложные союзы (несмотря на то что, для того чтобы). В нашем же случая это будет местоименная часть двойного или составного союза.

Comment: Просто местоимения — слова знаменательные. Союзы *несмотря на то что*, *для того чтобы* образованы из сочетаний, в которых слово "то" используется в качестве указательного местоимения. Слово "то", использованное при образовании союза "если… то", имеет чисто служебный характер. Оно не обозначает никакой предмет, признак или количество — оно обозначает причинно‑следственный характер связи между простыми предложениями.

Comment: Если вы так любите точность, то пусть это будет не местоимение, а местоименная часть союза, я не возражаю (просто  в коротком комментарии это  очень долго писать).